# Why does apt-get refuse to install cdefs.h (besides a symlink)?

Tags: apt, dpkg, kali-linux

I've been trying to install a 32 bit header to satisfy a dependency ridden package in *64 bit* Kali Linux this evening, and I don't know the Linux C build system well enough to debug this issue. The file is cdefs.h. It is my understanding that cdefs.h only occurs in 32 bit Linux.

The build process dies because it can't find cdefs.h, so I go on trying to hunt it down.

```
root@kali:~# dpkg -S /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
libc6-dev-i386: /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
```

So dpkg believes that cdefs.h exists in libc6-dev-i836

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6-dev-i386 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  lib32asan1 lib32atomic1 lib32cilkrts5 lib32gcc1 lib32gomp1 lib32itm1 lib32quadmath0 lib32stdc++6
  lib32ubsan0 libc6-amd64:i386 libltdl-dev xinit
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libc6-amd64 (2.19-18+deb8u3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u3) ...
```

Good to go right?

```
root@kali:~# locate cdefs.h
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/sys/cdefs.h
/usr/include/bsd/sys/cdefs.h
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/sys/cdefs.h
```

Oh no it's not there.

```
root@kali:~# ls /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
```

This is a symlink.

```
root@kali:~# cd /usr/include/sys/
root@kali:/usr/include/sys# ls
acct.h      fcntl.h     klog.h         procfs.h    sendfile.h   swap.h       timex.h        utsname.h
auxv.h      file.h      mman.h         profil.h    shm.h        syscall.h    ttychars.h     vfs.h
bitypes.h   fsuid.h     mount.h        ptrace.h    signalfd.h   sysctl.h     ttydefaults.h  vlimit.h
cdefs.h     gmon.h      msg.h          queue.h     signal.h     sysinfo.h    types.h        vm86.h
debugreg.h  gmon_out.h  mtio.h         quota.h     socket.h     syslog.h     ucontext.h     vt.h
dir.h       inotify.h   param.h        raw.h       socketvar.h  sysmacros.h  uio.h          vtimes.h
elf.h       ioctl.h     pci.h          reboot.h    soundcard.h  termios.h    ultrasound.h   wait.h
epoll.h     io.h        perm.h         reg.h       statfs.h     timeb.h      un.h           xattr.h
errno.h     ipc.h       personality.h  resource.h  stat.h       time.h       unistd.h
eventfd.h   kdaemon.h   poll.h         select.h    statvfs.h    timerfd.h    user.h
fanotify.h  kd.h        prctl.h        sem.h       stropts.h    times.h      ustat.h
```

All symlinks.

```
root@kali:/usr/include/sys# ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 12288 Aug 23 21:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 76 root root 20480 Aug 23 21:34 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    30 Feb 11  2016 acct.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/acct.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    30 Feb 11  2016 auxv.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/auxv.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    33 Feb 11  2016 bitypes.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/bitypes.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    31 Feb 11  2016 cdefs.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    34 Feb 11  2016 debugreg.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/debugreg.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    29 Feb 11  2016 dir.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/dir.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    29 Feb 11  2016 elf.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/elf.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    31 Feb 11  2016 epoll.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/epoll.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    31 Feb 11  2016 errno.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/errno.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    33 Feb 11  2016 eventfd.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/eventfd.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    34 Feb 11  2016 fanotify.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/fanotify.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    31 Feb 11  2016 fcntl.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/fcntl.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    30 Feb 11  2016 file.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/file.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    31 Feb 11  2016 fsuid.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/fsuid.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    30 Feb 11  2016 gmon.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/gmon.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    34 Feb 11  2016 gmon_out.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/gmon_out.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    33 Feb 11  2016 inotify.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/inotify.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    31 Feb 11  2016 ioctl.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/ioctl.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    28 Feb 11  2016 io.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/io.h
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    29 Feb 11  2016 ipc.h -> ../x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/ipc.h
```

Ah so I should just be able to check to where they point to make sure they are in good shape.

```
root@kali:/usr/include/sys# cd ../x86_64-linux-gnu/
root@kali:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu# ls
gnu
```

Wait what. Where's the sys folder everything is pointing to?

```
root@kali:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu# locate vfs.h
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gvfs.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.0.0-kali1-common/include/linux/vfs.h
root@kali:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu# locate cdefs.h
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/sys/cdefs.h
/usr/include/bsd/sys/cdefs.h
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/sys/cdefs.h
```

It's still not here. Am I missing something very dumb here? 
Why aren't the files advertised by dkpg being installed? 
What could be blocking them? 
Where should they exist? 
Why are the Windows are BSD versions of cdefs the only files around?

Comment: You need to run *updatedb* command to update *locate* database. Also, use *dpkg -L* to list files in a package.

Comment: Just updatedb in the terminal? Did nothing whatsoever for me, returned instantly so it's clearly not downloading anything.

Comment: If you have SSD, *updatedb* can be very fast. It printa nothing on success, but *locate* only finds files which existed when *updatedb* was last run.

Comment: So updatedb appears to have fixed the issue. One other problem I was having was that I installed the i386 libs rather than the amd64 libs.

Comment: "I realize everyone has mutually agreed it's very broken." :)
I don't really think that Kali is broken, but it's a specialised distro and not particularly newbie-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on comments:

The command long you have in your question shows `apt-get`, and then `locate` right after.

The way `locate` works is, it has it's own database for files in the file system. This database is updated with `updatedb` command, which is normally executed by `cron`, for example every night. So if you add (or remove) files, and want to use `locate` immediately after, you need to run `updatedb` (as root) yourself. After that `locate` will find your new files too.

This is rather useful to know for all programmers working on Linux, since needing to find files after installing something, or after doing a version control checkout, or just doing a build, is quite common, and using `find` is much slower than `locate`.